# Stuck working with JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

I have a JSON object that looks similar to

```
{
   "mydata":[
            "one",
            "two",
            "three"
            ],
   "outside":[
               {
                 "vals":["four", "five", "six"],
                 "soso":{"seven", "eight", "nine"]               
               },
               {
                 "vals":["four", "five", "six"],
                 "soso":{"seven", "eight", "nine"]               
               },
               {
                 "vals":["four", "five", "six"],
                 "soso":{"seven", "eight", "nine"]               
               },
              ]
   "inside":[]
```

and I am trying to with jquery run $.each on "outside" so I can get each vals set of values from "outside" and im not getting anything but am failing misserably ive given up hoping someone can assist

Comment: Please include a more complete code sample

Comment: Your JSON is invalid (i.e. the "soso" value starts as an object, but closes as an array - also, there is no comma before "inside" and no closing braces at the end). You can run it through http://jsonlint.com/ to test.  Once you have a valid JSON object, come back and explain your problem again.

Comment: to expand on what robrich was saying....  Please quote the applicable Jquery.  Also, a description of how it fails miserably might help.  (Is it returning wrong data?  Is it returning nulls?  Is the javascript in the page turning off altogether?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within `outside` object `soso` should look like this

`"soso":["seven", "eight", "nine"]` and then

```
$.each(json.outside, function() {
    this.vals.each(function(index, val) {
       console.log(val); // output: "four", "five", "six"
    });

   this.soso.each(function(index, val) {
       console.log(val); // output: "seven", "eight", "nine
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
$.each(jsonObj.outside, function () {
    var i = this; // The current item
});
```